# How to add each data inside a column of a table in both mysql and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, addition

I have a column name 'sale' and inside the sale column there are list of sales per customer. how do i add all the sales of each customer and then echo the total sales under the table?

[image]

```
> ?php
include('conn.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sales";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count>0)
    {
    echo "<html><head></head><body><table border=1>
        <th>CODE</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Sales</th>";

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {  
       echo"<tr>";      
        echo"<td>".$row['empcode']."</td>
             <td>".$row['fullname']."</td>
             <td>".$row['customercode']."</td>
             <td>".$row['sales']."</td></tr>";
        }
       echo"</table>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Add a variable to add sales in while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a variable outside of the loop and increment it with every iteration of the loop

```
$totalSales = 0;

if($count>0)
{
  echo "<html><head></head><body><table border=1>
    <th>CODE</th>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Sales</th>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {  
    echo"<tr>";      
    echo"<td>".$row['empcode']."</td>
         <td>".$row['fullname']."</td>
         <td>".$row['customercode']."</td>
         <td>".$row['sales']."</td></tr>";

     $totalSales += $row['sales'];
    }
   echo"</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you can use **SUM** group function.

e.g. `SELECT SUM(sales) as total FROM table_name;`

And for PHP, you can do something like this:

```
$total = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{  
    $total += $row['sales'];
    echo"<tr>";      
    echo"<td>".$row['empcode']."</td>
         <td>".$row['fullname']."</td>
         <td>".$row['customercode']."</td>
         <td>".$row['sales']."</td></tr>";
}
// Print total at the end
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='3'>Total</td>";
echo "<td>".$total."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

run

`$sql = "SELECT *, SUM(sales) AS total_sale FROM`sales`GROUP BY`customercode`";`

instead of

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales";`